# How to remove address and ASCII representation from a hex dump (delete certain columns)?

Tags: batch-file

I have a file with 50 lines. Each line looks like:

```
0000    30 82 02 ae 30 82 02 17  a0 03 02 01 02 02 09 00   0...0........... 
0010    d4 24 6e 23 50 8d 62 b4  30 0d 06 09 2a 86 48 86   .$n#P.b.0...*.H.
```

I want to write a batch script to delete the first and last part of the text file per each line. So that it looks like:

```
308202ae30820217a003020102020900d4246e23508d62b4300d06092a864886
```

How could this be done with a batch file using only standard Windows commands?

Comment: Do you want a hex dump of a file?  That can be done a different way.

Comment: Yes, I have a base64-coded file and want to have the data in hex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

< lang-dos -->

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "hexout="
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (q25263949.txt) DO (
 CALL :apphex %%a
)
ECHO %hexout%

GOTO :EOF
:apphex
shift
FOR /L %%c IN (1,1,16) DO CALL SET "hexout=%%hexout%%%%1"&shift
GOTO :eof
```

I used a file named `q25263949.txt` containing your data for my testing.

---

Hmm - you didn't say that the lines may not be complete. Unfortunately, you haven't posted an example of the short line. I'll assume that the line contains the hex values as before, but 1 to 16 of them and the ASCII decoding is aligned for the short line with that for the full lines.

< lang-dos -->

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "hexout="
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (q25263949.txt) DO (
 CALL :apphex "%%a"
)
ECHO %hexout%

GOTO :EOF
:apphex
IF "%~2"=="" GOTO splitit
shift
FOR /L %%c IN (1,1,16) DO CALL SET "hexout=%%hexout%%%%1"&shift
GOTO :eof

:splitit
SET "$1=%~1"
SET "$1=%$1:~0,56%"
CALL :apphex %$1%
GOTO :eof
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Exactly what I was searching for!

Comment: If my last line looks don't have all 16 hex characters (like:     0000 30 82 02 ae 30 82 02 17  a0 03 02 01    0...0...........) How can I avoid that the 0...0... is added to the new file?

Answer (score 0):

Using Swiss File Knife you can use this to get a hexdump.

```
sfk hexdump -pure -wide file.ext >file.txt
```

http://sourceforge.net/projects/swissfileknife/

Answer (score 0):

This simpler method should run faster:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "line="
for %%a in (a b c d e f g h   i j k l m n o p) do set "line=!line!%%%%a"
for /F "tokens=2-17" %%a in (file.txt) do echo %line%
```

... or via this even simpler, but uglier version:

```
@echo off
for /F "tokens=2-17" %%a in (file.txt) do echo %%a%%b%%c%%d%%e%%f%%g%%h%%i%%j%%k%%l%%m%%n%%o%%p
```